# Stopping MSBuild if a test fails

Tags: unit-testing, tfs, msbuild

I got around 530 unit tests in my project. Our msbuild takes around 15 minutes to run all these tests. If one of those 530 tests fail I want this to know immediately!

Sadly our MSbuild keeps running all the other 529 tests before it sends me a mail that the build 'partially succeeded'.

Is there a way to terminate the MSBuild proces and report the failed test immediately?

Comment: you need to edit build template or make your own custom activity

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to know if **other** tests are failing as well?

Comment: Which build system are you using? The old XAML build or the new VNext build?